# Wifi Hard Blocked After Suspend in Ubuntu on GS65

Tags: wireless, 18.04, iwlwifi, rfkill, airplane-mode

While GS65's wifi module, Killer 1550i(which is roughly Intel 9560), doesn't supported in \~4.17 kernels, I managed to get the wifi working by compiling latest *iwlwifi* kernel module and including them.

**But when I recover from the suspend, the wifi module is hard blocked(I could confirm this by `sudo rfkill list all`).**

After the hard block, the airplane mode cannot be turned off by `sudo rfkill unblock all` or `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. Googling suggests to use hardware airplane mode key, which is Fn+F10 on GS65, doesn't work in all situation(before/after hard block).

It's really frustrating since whenever I suspend my laptop for battery I have to reset it. Any help will be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with my GS65 too even after replacing the internal wifi card with a well supported Intel 8265NGW card instead.   I thought this would make all my wifi woes disappear, but life is never that simple.

Answer (score 18):

I have found another work-around for this, although it's not perfect.  Whilst airplane mode still will turn itself on and stay on after a suspend, at least this enables the hardware key `fn+F10` to allow you to get it back working again. Upon resume just double tap that key combo as quick as you like and you're back online.

To enable <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> add this line to your grub config in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' quiet splash"
```

To take effect, the grub configuration must be re-baked. You can achieve this by running the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

*(Updated after reading the comments below)*

Comment: As a follow on to [Gibbsofts answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057793/681688), you need to run: grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root, after you make the edits!

Comment: You can run `sudo update-grub` on Ubuntu to enable the changes.

Comment: this fix works, but then it will always use the discrete nvidia card ... Hibernate is an alternative, but I don't like it. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Also works well on a GS75 Stealth :)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem (with BestBuy model gs65) with Intel AC9560 wifi card on ubuntu 18.04.
I found workaround with this issue to enable lid close action with hibernating mode instead undefined in the /etc/systemd.logind.conf.
1. Open terminal to edit the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file.
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
2. Search for HandleLidSwitch line.
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate, hibernate when lid is closed
3. need to test if hibernate works first (if not make sure the swap space is larger than ram size. For BestBuy model, need to at lease 16G).

Hope it is working for you :-).

Comment: I can confirm that if you hibernate rather than suspend, the wireless card won't be blocked. I also own a gs65 and use nixos

Comment: @dave88 I already knew this but hibernation just sucks so hard lol