# Enters airplane mode after suspend / resume, can't toggle it

Tags: wireless, suspend, airplane-mode

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on an MSI GS65 Stealth Thin w/ a Nvidia Geforce 1070, and when I close the lid to suspend, and reopen the lid to resume, it often enters "airplane" mode and I don't see any way to turn it back on.

In the settings menu, it says "Use hardware switch to turn off".  When I hit the Fn key + the airplane key above F10 on the MSI keyboard, nothing seems to happen.

[image: Settings]

In the wifi settings it's turned off, and turning the button on doesn't have any effect.

[image]

I tried running `rfkill list all` and it returned:

`1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

Any tips on how to debug/fix this?

Answer (score 13):

I was able to workaround it using @Gibbsoft's answer in [Wifi Hard Blocked After Suspend in Ubuntu on GS65](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043547/wifi-hard-blocked-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-on-gs65).

Update `/etc/default/grub` with:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' quiet splash"`

And now after resuming, `fn` + `f10` takes it out of airplane mode and removes the hard block on the wifi driver.

Comment: This also worked on a P65 Creator (basically the same hardware)

Answer (score 1):

In addition you can also change settings for the laptop to hibernate instead of suspend. As mentioned on [this website:](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MSI_GS65#Wifi_is_hardblocked_(airplane_mode)_after_waking_up_from_suspend)
To avoid the hard block airplane mode you can change settings for the laptop to go into hibernate instead of suspend (you need to enable hibernate first):

In the file "/etc/systemd/logind.conf"
Change the following lines from "suspend" to "hibernate":
HandleSuspendKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate

Comment: still the same on ubuntu 22.04 on the msi laptops. Like this answer!