# Laptop with ubuntu 18.04 gets into flight mode when i close the lid

Tags: 18.04

The laptop is an msi gs65 stealth 8sg. I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 and when I close the lid or get in suspend mode the laptop gets into flight mode. I have to do a restart to switch it off.

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Click on the gear icon, then "System Settings", then "Power". Adjust the "Lid close" action there.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it didn't work for me. This answer worked though:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099929/enters-airplane-mode-after-suspend-resume-cant-toggle-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested this workaround by @tleyden (URL: [Enters airplane mode after suspend / resume, can't toggle it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099929/enters-airplane-mode-after-suspend-resume-cant-toggle-it)) worked:

Update /etc/default/grub with:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' quiet splash"

And now after resuming, fn + f10 takes it out of airplane mode and removes the hard block on the wifi driver.