# Cannot disable airplane mode on laptop with faulty lid sensor

Tags: lid, airplane-mode

**Problem** : Unable to disable airplane mode. It says use hardware switch to turn off.

**OS** : Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

**Laptop Model** : HP 15 r074tu

**Description** : The lid sensor of of laptop is not working. In windows I use Fn + F12 key to toggle airplane mode and it works, but ubuntu I am not able to toggle, it boots up with airplane mode enabled by default.
Is it possible that it is happening because of lid is not working. I have seen threads mentioning people having problem of airplane mode where lid operation set to suspend.

**What I have tried :**

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-cannot-disable-airplane-mode/
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-the-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04/
[Enters airplane mode after suspend / resume, can't toggle it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099929/enters-airplane-mode-after-suspend-resume-cant-toggle-it)

last part of this https://dev1galaxy.org/viewtopic.php?id=2021

Output of some debugging commands
https://pastebin.com/7FexyPmV

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398739&highlight=hp-wmi

Comment: This solution suggests taping pin 20 in hardware card, I am not good with hardware.

Comment: I regret that I haven't any further suggestions. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned solution worked:
Edit your kernel boot parameter with:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Look for the line with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash acpi=off" <--parameters may defer based on your system - ->
Within the " " (quotes), replace acpi=off or any other acpi parameters with acpi_osi=!.

e.g.: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash acpi_osi=!"

Press Ctrl+O to Save and Confirm Change
Press Ctrl+X to return to terminal

Update grub with :
sudo update-grub

Reboot your machine

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-hp-pavilion-dv4-ubuntu-18-04-airplane-mode-enabled-wifi-and-bluetooth-not-working/