# Ubuntu 18.04 / iwlwifi : recurrent problems, now Airplane Mode activated and impossible to remove after suspend

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, iwlwifi

**Major Edit : the problem about "sudo modprobe iwlwifi" is solved ! I reset BIOS settings to optimized defaults and the problem disappeared on both Windows and Ubuntu. However, now I still have airplane mode activated and impossible to switch off after suspend.**

**Major Edit : I've tried on Windows and the Wi-Fi driver could not be loaded as well. Something really went wrong!**

Dear AskUbuntu community,

Using a MSI P65 Creator 8RF laptop, I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop. It is my first use of Ubuntu ever.

I am facing recurrent problems with the Wi-Fi driver. I have been facing the well-known problem with the system often switching to airplane mode after suspend, without me being unable to stop it unless suspending and logging in again one or several times.

My Wi-Fi card is Intel Wireless-AC 9560.

I tried to unload and reload iwlwifi by performing :

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

The first line indeed removed any form of Wi-Fi options on the desktop, but the second line now did not and still does not perform anything. Now I find myself unable to even restart the Wi-Fi. All the drivers seem up-to-date and rebooting does not help.

Does someone have any clue ?

Thank you in advance ! I am new to both Ubuntu and this forum, so I apologize if the question is ill-asked. If you need any other information, like the output of any terminal command line, I will edit the topic and show the answer.

**EDIT 1 :** thank you Chili555, so :

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.071654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.080785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.103001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    3.150716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    3.150722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    3.150989] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2459
[    3.151277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    3.166429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  571.628552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[  571.640682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[  571.686727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[  571.686734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[  571.686843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2458
[  571.686848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[  571.699125] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Before I removed iwlwifi with modprobe -r, "rfkill list all" would also show the Wi-Fi.

**Edit 2 :**

```
ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 9000
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2632620 avril 24  2018 iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2677620 janv. 24 13:59 iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2520568 déc.  14 13:54 iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
```

For your information, I also tried to reinstall the iwlwifi from Intel's website, maybe it explains why there are more than 1 result here. Of course, this procedure dit not help. I don't know if it made anything worse!

** Edit 3:**

Tried to reinstall the drivers but still have :

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.115860] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.124078] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.3125811985.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.158887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    3.208187] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    3.208190] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    3.208246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2458
[    3.208248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    3.220168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 : thank you for your help, I have just edited

Comment: This suggests a firmware fault and I wonder if your firmware file is corrupted. Please also add: `ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 9000` On my machine, the relevent file is: 2678284 Nov  6 09:30 iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode

Comment: @chili555 : yes it is highly possible. For your information, I also tried to reinstall the iwlwifi from Intel's website, it did not lead to much more success. I have added this command

Comment: I suspect that, in so doing, you reverted to an earlier firmware file, not later. Please install this, reboot and let us see: `dmesg | grep iwl` http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.175.1_all.deb

Comment: @chili555 : it looks like nothing changed, I still have the same output for dmesg | grep iwl... The firmware was for sure faulty even before this manipulation

Comment: In `dmesg | grep iwl` is firmware version -34 the only version sought and loaded? Or is the a sequence before it finds -34? If you reboot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu, does the wireless work?

Comment: Yes, the version -34 is the only one sought and loaded. I have just rebooted with an earlier version of the kernel, but it did not change much.

Comment: Edit : major problem : the driver is not recognized in Windows either now !

Comment: Edit : the problem about "sudo modprobe iwlwifi" is solved ! I reset BIOS settings to optimized defaults and the problem disappeared on both Windows and Ubuntu. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest you remove the solution from the question, and add it as an answer. Please also remove 'Solved' from the title, and instead [accept your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). This way it will show as solved in the overview of questions, the correct solution will be evident, and useful to future googlers :)

Comment: In fact, everything is still not solved, as I still have airplane mode activated and impossible to switch off after suspend. Sorry for the confusion, but before I had two problems, now I switched back to "only" one.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem solved ! I managed to (seemingly) solve the Airplane Mode by performing the following :**

1) Added this in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' quiet splash"
```

2) Ran in Terminal :

```
sudo update-grub
```

3) Rebooted

Now I can use my Fn + F10 keyboard combination to activate and deactivate Airplane Mode on my own.

Credits to : [Wifi Hard Blocked After Suspend in Ubuntu on GS65](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043547/wifi-hard-blocked-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-on-gs65/1058248#1058248)

Thank you for your help guys !

Answer (score 1):

Try instead (as `root`)

`modprobe -r iwlwifi`

`modprobe -i iwlwifi` or `

My laptop had the same issue with some dkms modules and these commands worked for me my wifi module was `8821ce`

Always see manual pages first they are always helpful

`man modprobe`

There is bug related to this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1710390

If the above commanda fails then try searching the website it have some workarounds

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not change anything... But thank you still. Edit : saw the link before but I will try to have a deeper look, thanks!

Comment: Edit : the problem about "sudo modprobe iwlwifi" is solved ! I reset BIOS settings to optimized defaults and the problem disappeared on both Windows and Ubuntu. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a WORKAROUND of the problem by simply changing how my laptop responds to lid closing. Simply, use the command

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "HandleLidSwitch=lock" >> /etc/systemd/logind.conf' && reboot
```

It will now LOCK the computer every time lid closes instead of suspending and hence no problem of AIRPLANE MODE.