# 18.04 "No wifi adapter found"

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I'm no longer able to use Wifi on my lenovo thinkpad p1 after a recent update from Ubuntu (i think at least). And I'm desperately looking for some guidance if it's the chip or if it's a driver issue.

This is probably a duplicate of another question but all the other ones I've seen talk about either Realtek or a Qualcomm based wifi chip. Mine is the 9560 from Intel. And I'm seeing the following output within the script provided by: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/972343

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7C2NvXxXKH/

And this is what i see when running `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    6.947040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.022558] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.c0e03d94.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.077003] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    7.319388] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    7.319393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    7.319451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x240f
[    7.319455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    7.333073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

And some additional information provided by `lspci -v | grep Network`

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

Comment: @mchid I have rebooted multiple times since the issue started. And ensured all updates were installed (through apt update/apt upgrade and the ubuntu software center updater)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out -- apparently I had activated an invisible airplane mode through one of the function keys.

Thanks to @MrOrgon who I found by accident while googling. His comment made me think: Could it really be that easy...

[Ubuntu 18.04 / iwlwifi : recurrent problems, now Airplane Mode activated and impossible to remove after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112505/ubuntu-18-04-iwlwifi-recurrent-problems-now-airplane-mode-activated-and-imp/1112596#1112596)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once , can't remember if dmesg showed the board but ....
The discovery process of a life- cd/usb found/reseted and activated the wifi board. 
I just started up the computer from usb and checked if the wifi was recognized after that I could reboot the computer and my old system was able to use the wifi board. as if a setting in the board had to be reset.

Good luck with it !

Comment: Tried booting from a bootable usb drive (ubuntu 18.04.2) same result and same errors as reported above