# HP laptop goes into AIRPLANE mode after suspend.How to fix it?

Tags: wireless, suspend, hp, lid, airplane-mode

I recently added Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 to my laptop (**HP pavilion 15 ab032tx**). Everything works fine except:

When I close the lid, then later reopen it,  Ubuntu goes into airplane mode and <kbd>F12</kbd> to clear airplane mode does not work.  I have to reboot the laptop to reestablish WiFi.

I have tried resetting my BIOS settings which did not solve the problem.

Result of `rfkill --output ID,TYPE`

```
ID TYPE   
 1 wlan
```

How may I troubleshoot this to solve the problem?

Comment: does your laptop have a hardware switch?  There are a couple of questions that may be related to your topic and perhaps there is already an answer here.  See: [search results of "suspend airplane" sorted by votes](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=suspend%20airplane).  Can you look through these and come back and make an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1215369/edit) with the results of your research and attempts to fix (and the outcome of those attempts)

Comment: ID 1 TYPE wlan.  Something like this is coming. @K7AAY

Comment: @K7AAY there is no problem as such in my Windows  10. Only in ubuntu 

Comment: I think it may be something in your settings. You can adjust that in your Ubuntu 18.04 settings application, in the internet/communications one. It is not labeled that way.

Comment: @Jeff I tried turning **ON** the WiFi from the settings but no luck.

Comment: @K7AAY thanks for editing...that's exactly the output 

Comment: Please try _rfkill unblock wlan_ again - and http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code  shows how to use formatting in questions

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a **WORKAROUND** of the problem by simply changing how my laptop responds to lid closing. Simply, use the command
`sudo sh -c 'echo "HandleLidSwitch=lock" >> /etc/systemd/logind.conf' && reboot`
It will now **LOCK** the computer every time lid closes instead of suspending and hence no problem of AIRPLANE MODE.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's still useful, I've been struggling with the same for years. I probably tried every fix suggested online, everything that seemed to work for someone just didn't have an effect locally. After long struggling I just accepted that there's no actual fix online. Deep inside I just couldn't really believe it, though, I couldn't understand why it would work under Windows but not under Linux, so from time to time I had another look online. I also did the lock-fix long ago, but didn't really like it; closing my laptop, putting it in my bag for a couple of days while forgetting that it was actually not suspended or shut down, and having an empty battery when wanting to use my laptop again :-)

**In any case today I seem to have found a fix here, wich worked for me: [Wifi Hard Blocked After Suspend in Ubuntu on GS65](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043547/wifi-hard-blocked-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-on-gs65)**

Despite their post not being for an HP, it fixed it for me locally nonetheless. According to [this link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi_osilinux-do/), I understand that their suggested fix is "*lying to the BIOS, making it think it's running Windows*"? It feels like a weird solution (makes sense in a way, but then again, still feels weird), and I've only used it for a couple of hours. Who knows what I will discover in the next few days/weeks/months, I feel like that fix could show some surprises along the way ... YMMV but just in case it helps, I wanted to put that fix out there!