# Airplane Mode turns on automatically

Tags: bluetooth, hp, hardware, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

I am using an HP Pavilion 15 ab032tx laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot.

Whenever I shut the lid down and then reopen it, the airplane mode turns on automatically.

#### Here is what I tried:

I tried to turn it off from settings but the toggle button is all greyed and I can't access it. I also tried

```bsh
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

But it has no effect. I tried to put the `HandleLidSwitch` to ignore but that also didn't work. Also tried the solution in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04) but it also didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Start feature. That helps in most of cases.

Comment: Windows Fast startup is already disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround to allow you to create a hardware key `fn+F10` to toggle Airplane Mode off after suspend:

Add this line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' quiet splash"
```

Then update your grub config:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Source: [Gibbsoft](https://askubuntu.com/users/580719/gibbsoft)'s answer to [Wifi Hard Blocked After Suspend in Ubuntu on GS65](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043547/wifi-hard-blocked-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-on-gs65)

Comment: It worked! Thankyou very much for the help.

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this solution helped me.
In terminal run `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/hp-keycodes.service` than insert this text in to the file and save it:

```
[Unit] 
Description=HP setkeycodes fix

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=no
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setkeycodes e057 240 e058 240

[Install]
WantedBy=rescue.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

After that reload and enable service:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl enable hp-keycodes.service`

And finally restart your computer and check the result!
[Source](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/disable-automatic-airplane-mode-ubuntu/)